# How to change password of multiple ZIP archive files at once?

Tags: encryption, passwords, compression, zip, 7-zip

I have 50 password protected ZIP compressed archive files.  By design, all the files have the same password.

I now want to change the password for all those ZIP files to a different password (again, keeping the password the same for each ZIP file).

What is a quick and easy way to accomplish this task in Windows?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @hedgie Oh dear. I can't believe I left that out.  Let me update the question real quick.  Thank you for pointing out my omission.